# CSS no longer applying with keter and nginx reverse proxy setup

Tags: css, nginx, haskell, yesod, keter

**Problem**: CSS was being applied to the site but after switching to reverse proxy and adding a security cert while changing nothing else, the CSS no longer loads.

**Details**: Initially the website was using keter only with no security cert or reverse proxy. The site worked fine as intended. The `yesod-devel` command correctly renders the site. Once compiled, the styling does not appear on the final site. Before the switch to reverse proxy, everything worked as desired. No other changes were made except to config files related to the reverse proxy and security cert.

**Dependencies**: The dependencies are at this https://gist.github.com/xave/9cdf396c1918c129aff927ab8999d456.

**Workflow**: The main dev machine is macOS. The server is Ubuntu. The workflow is to develop and preview on macOS, then to compile and deploy on Ubuntu.

**Thoughts**:All the CSS is on the page upon inspection. It just isn’t applying. This is true for multiple browsers and even for people who had never before visited the site (so not a caching issue).

Any help would be appreciated and please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Has no one had a similar issue to this? I feel like someone who does web development would have an idea of the best place to look at least.

Comment: If the site is served with https://, all CSS/JS must also be linked with https://, not http://. That is, the HTML must use HTTPS-URLs in `<style>`/`<script>` tags.